# using SIMD operation from C# in .NET framework 4.6 is slower

Tags: c#, .net, ryujit

I am currently trying to calculate the sum of all the values in a huge array using just C# and using SIMD to compare performance and the SIMD version is considerably slower. Please see code snippets below and let me know if I am missing something. "vals" is the huge array that is read from an image file and omitted that part out to keep it lean.

```
var watch1 = new Stopwatch();
watch1.Start();
var total = vals.Aggregate(0, (a, i) => a + i);
watch1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total is: {0}", total));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time taken: {0}", watch1.ElapsedMilliseconds));

var watch2 = new Stopwatch();
watch2.Start();
var sTotal = GetSIMDVectors(vals).Aggregate((a, i) => a + i);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Vector<int>.Count; i++)
    sum += sTotal[i];
watch2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Another Total is: {0}", sum));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time taken: {0}", watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds));
```

and the GetSIMDVectors method

```
private static IEnumerable<Vector<int>> GetSIMDVectors(short[] source)
{
    int vecCount = Vector<int>.Count;
    int i = 0;
    int len = source.Length;
    for(i = 0; i + vecCount < len; i = i + vecCount)
    {
        var items = new int[vecCount];
        for (int k = 0; k < vecCount; k++)
        {
            items[k] = source[i + k];
        }
        yield return new Vector<int>(items);
    }
    var remaining = new int[vecCount];
    for (int j = i, k =0; j < len; j++, k++)
    {
        remaining[k] = source[j];
    }
    yield return new Vector<int>(remaining);
}
```

Comment: Are you running with optimizations on (i.e. Release mode) and in 64-bit (make sure you are not using Any CPU with prefer 32-bit)? You can verify that SIMD is being used via [Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated(v=vs.111).aspx).

Comment: That was it. Wasn't running in 64 bit mode.

Comment: mike, if you post an answer i can mark it so

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @mike z has indicated, you need to make sure you are in release mode  and targeting 64-bit or else RuyJIT, the compiler supporting SIMD, won't work(As for now it is only supported on 64-bit architectures).
Also checking before execution is always a good practice to follow using:

```
Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated;
```

Also, you need not to use a for loop to create an array first before creating the vector. You shold simply create the vector from the original source array using the `vector<int>(int[] array,int index)` constructor.

```
yield return new Vector<int>(source, i);
```

instead of

```
var items = new int[vecCount];
for (int k = 0; k < vecCount; k++)
{
    items[k] = source[i + k];
}
yield return new Vector<int>(items);
```

This way, i managed to get nearly **3.7x** increase in performance using a randomly generated large array.

Moreover, if you were to change your method with a one that directly calculates the sum as soon as it gets the valew of the `new Vector<int>(source, i)`, like this:

```
private static int GetSIMDVectorsSum(int[] source)
    {
        int vecCount = Vector<int>.Count;
        int i = 0;
        int end_state = source.Length;

        Vector<int> temp = Vector<int>.Zero;


        for (; i < end_state; i += vecCount)
        {
            temp += new Vector<int>(source, i);

        }

        return Vector.Dot<int>(temp, Vector<int>.One);


    }
```

The performance increases more dramatically here. I managed to get a **16x** increase in performance over `vals.Aggregate(0, (a, i) => a + i)` in my tests.

However, from a theoretical point of view, if for example `Vector<int>.Count`returns 4, then anything above a **4x** increase in performance indicates that you are comparing the vectorized version to a relatively unoptimized code.

That will be the `vals.Aggregate(0, (a, i) => a + i)` portion in your case. So basically, there is a plenty of room for you to optimize here.

When i replace it with a trivial for loop

```
private static int no_vec_sum(int[] vals)
{
    int end = vals.Length;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        temp += vals[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

i only get a **1.5x** increase in performance. Still an improvement though, for this very particular case, considering the simplicity of the operation.

Needless to say that **Large** arrays are required for the vectorized version to overcome the overhead induced by creating `new Vector<int>()` in each iteration.